# Are binary characters legal in MIME headers?

Tags: character-encoding, mime

I work on a server that processes email, and as part of that, we do some MIME parsing/encoding.  I've recently had an issue arise for a message that is valid otherwise, but contains a Latin-1 character in a MIME header.  Someone entered an e-mail address to multiple recipients containing a Latin-1 character, so the SMTP envelope only contains the valid recipients, but the To line still contains the invalid address and improperly-encoded string.

It was my impression that this is illegal, and that MIME headers are required to be 7-bit.  8-bit values in MIME headers have to be encoded in the form

```
=?charset?encoding?encoded text?=
```

The header in question is something like this:

```
To: <changéd@someplace.com>, <secondaddress@someplace.com>
```

**My question is:** Is this valid MIME and I just don't know about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), *Internet Message Format*, section 2.2, **Header Fields**:

> Header fields are lines composed of a field name, followed by a colon
> (":"), followed by a field body, and terminated by CRLF.  A field
> name MUST be composed of printable US-ASCII characters (i.e.,
> characters that have values between 33 and 126, inclusive), except
> colon.  A field body may be composed of any US-ASCII characters,
> except for CR and LF.  However, a field body may contain CRLF when
> used in header "folding" and  "unfolding" as described in section
> 2.2.3.  All field bodies MUST conform to the syntax described in
> sections 3 and 4 of this standard.

Therefore, any non-ASCII characters are illegal.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 822 says](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html):

```
 address     =  mailbox                      ; one addressee
 mailbox     =  addr-spec                    ; simple address
 addr-spec   =  local-part "@" domain        ; global address
 local-part  =  word *("." word)             ; uninterpreted
 word        =  atom / quoted-string     
 atom        =  1*<any CHAR except specials, SPACE and CTLs>
 CHAR        =  <any ASCII character>        ; (  0-177,  0.-127.)
```

got it? your option is "quoted-string" - `=?charset?encoding?encoded text?=`

Comment: Yeah, I definitely know the address is invalid, but I'm not attempting to parse the To: line itself for interpretation.  I'm just wondering if it's even valid to have non-ASCII characters in a MIME header at all.

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses like

```
changéd@someplace.com
```

are perfectly legal *if* the characters are encoded in UTF-8 and *if* the server supports SMTPUTF8, an extension to SMTP.  The server advertises support by responding to EHLO with the SMTPUTF8 keyword:

```
250-SMTPUTF8
```

The client utilizes the extension by adding the SMTPUTF8 parameter on the MAIL command:

```
MAIL FROM:<changéd@someplace.com> SMTPUTF8
```

Sadly, there is very little support for this extension at this time.

See RFC 6531 for more info:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531